# Nest function n times

Tags: difference-equations, operators

A trivial example would be

```
f[x_]:=x
Nest[f, 7, n]
```

which would of course be `7` because it is independent of `n`, but `Nest` requires a machine integer for `n`.

A little reading took me to `RsolveValue`

```
RSolveValue[{x[n + 1] == f[x[n]], x[0] == 7}, x[n], n]
```

which gives me `7`, hooray!

Unfortunately, if I change `f`:

```
f[x_]:=0
RSolveValue[{x[n + 1] == f[x[n]], x[0] == 7}, x[n], n]
```

gives me `RSolveValue[{x[1 + n] == 0, x[0] == 7}, x[n], n]` and the error `For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution`

I guess it's right to complain, because my boundary condition violates the difference equation. But what I'm looking for is the answer `0`

So how can I make this work?

The ultimate goal I have is finding the n'th repeated application of arbitrary operators on a given starting expression.

Comment: "finding the n'th repeated application of arbitrary operators on a given starting expression" is exactly what `Nest` does, but you have to provide a value for `n`. Not clear what you are trying to do that is different from that.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I am trying to find the answer for any `n`, i.e. an expression in terms of `n`